# How to make and class array to define what class use to next instance?

Tags: c++, c++11

I usually works with python and I keep the mind of this language. So I want to make an array or struct like that:

```
struct instanceType = {
std::string name,
class typeOfclass
};
```

The idea is to run a loop to check from a string list a match with instanceType and get from this the class for instance a new object. e.g.

```
instanceType type1;
type1.name = "Type1";
type1.class = Class1;
instanceType type2;
type1.name = "Type2";
type1.class = Class2;
int implementTypes = 2;
instanceType typesArray[implementTypes] = {type1, type2};

// This is the goal I want
...
for(int i=0; i < implementTypes; ++i) {
    for(const std::string& objectToCreate; objectsToCreate) {
        if(typesArray[i].name==objectToCreate) {
            typesArray[i].class newObject = typesArray[i]() //"Constructor"
        }
    }
}
```

It could be crazy but it would be very useful to be able to use something similar.

Comment: You can use [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) for a similar purpose. Do note the difference between dynamic and static types though. However, please edit your question to add an actual **answerable question**.

Comment: It's not possible to store a type, and what you're doing might even be bad design. What is the *real* problem you want to solve by something like this? What are your requirements? Your use-cases? And what prevents you from using factory functions?

Comment: @Some programmer dude, not necessarily bad design (in general at least). For instance, this could be extremely useful when implementing network data serialization/deserialization for types (classes) that are not known at compile time. Anyway, c++ doesn't support this.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, this small code will be part of a factory c++ design patern and I think It's not a good idea implement another factory functions into a well-designed and ready patern deployed.

Comment: You should really forget about Python when writing C++. They are different languages with different idioms.

Comment: Do these types have any commonality? What are you going to do with the `newObject ` once you have created it?

Comment: @caleth newObject is manage by other classes. This is not the question. Finally, all objects will be reachable by a shared_ptr so more actual code could be:
std::share_ptr<typesArray[i]> myPtr = std::make_shared<typesArray[i]> (typesArray[i]());

Comment: That still doesn't answer whether there is commonality between these types. You **could** have `std::shared_ptr<SomeBaseClass> myPtr = factory[i].make_shared();` but that requires the all the types you are constructing here inherit from `SomeBaseClass`. You **could** have `std::any myThing = factory[i].make();`, however there then isn't anything interesting you can do with `myThing`

Comment: If the list of types is constant, you **could** have `std::variant<Class1, Class2> newObject = factory[i].make();`. Which of these options is most appropriate depends on *what you do with `newObject`*